# Is every finite ring a matrix algebra over a commutative ring?

Tags: ring-theory, finite-rings

[In this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27357/what-are-your-favorite-finite-non-commutative-rings/27364#27364) it is stated that every finite ring is a direct sum of finite-dimensional algebras over $\mathbb{Z}/p^k$ for varying $p$ and $k.$ What I am wondering is the following:

- Can every finite ring $R$ be written as a subring of $\text{Mat}_{n\times n}A$ for some commutative ring $A$?
- If not, then what is/are the smallest ring(s) that cannot be?

Sorry if this question is trivial for some reason (something like the regular representation or permuation representation?), or if I should have asked a question about algebras, or ideals, or modules, instead.

Comment: Duplicate, but the original doesn't contain a solution: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454097/presentation-of-finite-rings-fields

Comment: Since there is no indication the other question has "commutative" where this one does, it's not quite a duplicate.

Comment: Well, if you don't stick "commutative" in there then it's not very interesting. I'm willing to give the OP the benefit of the doubt.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the answer is [no](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/257002451_On_the_embedding_of_finite_rings_into_matrices), and the smallest counterexample has order $2^5 = 32$. I suspect it is $\text{End}(\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_4)$, but don't quote me on that. (By looking at the action of a finite ring on itself by left multiplication you can reduce the question to endomorphism rings of finite abelian groups, and by looking at each prime separately you can reduce the question to endomorphism rings of finite abelian $p$-groups. That ring above is the simplest such ring which isn't already a matrix ring.)